# Generación de números aleatorios de una distribución Tukey

Tags: r

Estoy tratado de generar números aleatorios de una variable que distribuye Tukey; pero no sé cuáles son sus parámetros y cómo puedo generarlos en R.

Comment: No me parece que sea demasiado amplia. La pregunta es muy clara. Si a mí me dicen cómo generar una variable que tiene una distribución normal, diría que con rnorm y los parámetros correspondientes. Pero no sé como sea con Tukey y mucho menos en el caso bivariado. Muchas gracias

Comment: Mira [la documentacion de PoweR](http://search.r-project.org/library/PoweR/html/law0018.Tukey.html) que permite hacerlo con la funcion `gensample`. El ejemplo dado es: `res <- gensample(18,10000,law.pars=8)` donde tus numeros estan en `res$sample` .

Answer (score 1):

Para conocer más acerca de la distribución Tukey puede ver el siguiente enlace [Dist. Tukey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tukey_lambda_distribution/), el paquete `estraDistr`, genera aleatorios de esta dstribución. La distribución de Tukey lambda es una distribución de probabilidad continua definida en términos de su función de cuantiles. Normalmente se usa para identificar otras distribuciones. Con Función Quantil definida como:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con parámetro λ∈ℝ. Por ejemplo λ = 0.14 es una distribución normal.

```
library(extraDistr)
hist(rtlambda(1e5, 0.14), freq = FALSE, main = "lambda = 0.14 (normal)")
```

Como puede ver en la imagen de wikipedia esta es una distribución simétrica centrada en cero. Si necesita generar de la distribución bivariada, es porque no es simétrica y necesita generar aleatorios de la distribución Tukey asimétrica o 
generalizada. El paquete `gld` de R resuelve este problema. ver la página 9 de [gld](ftp://cran.r-project.org/pub/R/web/packages/gld/gld.pdf). La parametrización por defecto (FMKL) es la debida a Freimer Mudholkar, Kollia y Lin (1988), con una función cuantil definida por:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para usar esta función necesita ingresar los siguientes parámetros n que es el numero de aleatorios a generar y sus parámetros (λ1, λ2>0, λ3, λ4). Pongo un ejemplo:

```
library(gld)
rgl(n, lambda1=0, lambda2 = NULL, lambda3 = NULL, lambda4 = NULL, param = "fkml", lambda5 = NULL)
# Ejemplo
rgl(5, lambda1 = 0, lambda2 = 3, lambda3 = 4, lambda4 = 2)
[1] -0.012941983 -0.041636281  0.073988595  0.006815349 -0.063176389
```

Ahora que si lo que usted tiene es unos datos en un vector digamos x, y supone que son de una distribución Tukey pero no sabe de que parámetros podría estimarlos por máxima verosimilitud, con el siguiente comando.

```
library(gld)
x <- c(3,4,5,6,7,3,7)
fit.fkml(x)
Maximum Likelihood estimate, gld type: fkml 
lambda1  lambda2  lambda3  lambda4  
  4.705    0.422    1.389    1.032
```